# making a rondom maze generated map

Tags: javascript

i am a begginer in javascript and i am trying to make a maze game, i followed the instructions on yt to generate random maze map. but when we came to the end and i tried to generete it. it wouldnt work. then i then i checked it in validator and console if there are any problems with it and i couldnt find any of it. so i here i am asking anyone could help me.

this is my code:

```js
let maze = document.querySelector(".maze");
let ctx = maze.getContext("2d"); 

let current;

class Maze{
    constructor(size,rows,columns){
        this.size = size;
        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = columns;
        this.grid = [];
        this.stack = [];
    }

    setup(){
        for(let r = 0; r < this.rows; r++){
            let row = [];
            for (let c = 0; c < this.columns; c++){
                let cell = new Cell(r,c, this.grid,this.size);
                row.push(cell);
            }
            this.grid.push(row);
        }
        current = this.grid[0][0];
    }
    draw(){
        maze.width=this.size;
        maze.height=this.size;
        maze.style.background = "black";
        current.visited = true;

        for (let r = 0; r < this.rows; r++) {
            for (let c = 0; c < this.columns; c++) {
              let grid = this.grid;
              grid[r][c].show(this.size, this.rows, this.columns);
            }
        }

        let next = current.checkNeighbours();

        if (next) {
            next.visited = true;
            this.stack.push(current);
            current.highlight(this.columns);
            current.removeWalls(current, next);
            current = next;
      
          }else if (this.stack.length > 0) {
            let cell = this.stack.pop();
            current = cell;
            current.highlight(this.columns);
          }

        if(this.stack.length == 0){
            return;
        }
        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            this.draw();
        });

        
    }
}

class Cell{
    constructor(rowNum,colNum,parentGrid,parentSize){
        this.rowNum = rowNum;
        this.colNum = colNum;
        this.parentGrid = parentGrid;
        this.parentSize = parentSize;
        this.visited = false;
        this.walls = {
            topWall : true,
            rightWall : true,
            bottomWall : true,
            leftwall : true,

        };
    }
    checkNeighbours() {
        let grid = this.parentGrid;
        let row = this.rowNum;
        let col = this.colNum;
        let neighbours = [];

        let top = row !== 0 ? grid[row-1][col] : undefined;
        let right = col !== grid.length-1 ? grid[row][col+1] : undefined;
        let bottom = row !== grid.length-1 ? grid[row+1][col] : undefined;
        let left = col !== 0 ? grid[row][col-1] : undefined;

        if(top && !top.visited) neighbours.push(top);
        if(right && !right.visited) neighbours.push(right);
        if(bottom && !bottom.visited) neighbours.push(bottom);
        if(left && !left.visited) neighbours.push(left);

        if(neighbours,length !== 0){
            let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * neighbours.length);
            return neighbours[random];
        }else{
            return undefined;
        }
    }

    drawTopWall(x,y,size,columns){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, y);
        ctx.lineTo(x + size / columns, y);
         ctx.stroke();
    }

    drawRightWall(x,y,size,columns,rows){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x + size / columns, y);
        ctx.lineTo(x + size / columns, y + size / rows);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    drawBottomWall(x,y,size,columns,rows){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, y + size / rows);
        ctx.lineTo(x + size / columns, y + size / rows);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    drawLeftWall(x,y,size,columns,rows){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, y);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y + size / rows);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    highlight(columns){
        let x = (this.colNum * this.parentSize) / columns + 1;
    let y = (this.rowNum * this.parentSize) / columns + 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
    ctx.fillRect(
      x,
      y,
      this.parentSize / columns - 3,
      this.parentSize / columns - 3
    );
    }

    removeWall(cell1,cell2){
        let x = cell1.colNum - cell2.colNum;

        if (x === 1) {
            cell1.walls.leftWall = false;
            cell2.walls.rightWall = false;
          } else if (x === -1) {
            cell1.walls.rightWall = false;
            cell2.walls.leftWall = false;
          }

          let y = cell1.rowNum - cell2.rowNum;

          if (y === 1) {
            cell1.walls.topWall = false;
            cell2.walls.bottomWall = false;
          } else if (y === -1) {
            cell1.walls.bottomWall = false;
            cell2.walls.topWall = false;
          }

    }

    show(size,rows,columns){
        let x = (this.colNum * size) / columns;
        let y = (this.rowNum * size) / rows;

        ctx.strokeStyle = "White";
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;

        if (this.walls.topWall) this.drawTopWall(x, y, size, columns, rows);
        if (this.walls.rightWall) this.drawRightWall(x, y, size, columns, rows);
        if (this.walls.bottomWall) this.drawBottomWall(x, y, size, columns, rows);
        if (this.walls.leftwall) this.drawLeftWall(x, y, size, columns, rows);
        if(this.visited){
            ctx.fillRect(x + 1, y + 1, size / columns - 2, size / rows - 2);
        }
    }
}

let newMaze = new Maze(700,20,20);
newMaze.setup();
newMaze.draw();
```

```html
    <canvas class="maze"></canvas>
```

Comment: When I run your code it generates a canvas of black squares with white borders.  Is that the same result that you get?  What result did you expect?

Comment: this line `if(neighbours,length !== 0){` doesn't look right. Maybe you want `if(neighbours.length !== 0){`  (note the dot instead of the comma)

Comment: to James yes what i got was a canvas of black squares with white borders

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
if(neighbours,length !== 0){
 ...
}
```

doesn't look right. Maybe you want `if(neighbours.length !== 0){ ... }` (note the dot instead of the comma).

Also,
`current.removeWalls()` should be `current.removeWall()` (without the "s")